# App on iOS device randomly quits when launching

Tags: swift, crash, device

I've been running my app on my phone for over a month now. The code compiles fine and everything. Yesterday morning, I clicked on it to show my friend and as it came up, it crashed. Crashed as in what would happen when it finds nil. Then if I quit the app(swiped up) and tried again it still would not launch.I kept clicking on it over and over, but still not result. When I got home, I ran it on my Mac again and now it works fine. Why would the app have been crashing out of the blue like that?

Comment: crash log ?......

Comment: It wasn't connected to my computer at that time.

Comment: expired certificate?

Comment: Xcode builds that run on device only have a short lifespan. They are not supposed to be used for deploying usable apps. After a few days the app will stop working and will need to be added again. You can use TestFlight builds for upto 90 days (If i remember rightly). other than that, publish it

Answer (score 0):

Running an app on your device only lasts for so long. It expires after a while, so you need to run it again.